# localhost took too long to respond - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, localhost, citrix

In Windows 10,
my application that runs on localhost stopped working after connecting and then disconnecting from the VPN (Citrix).
[image]

Restart the app - doesn't help.
Tried this without success:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
```

Also, disable Firewall, etc\hosts is ok, proxy is not set.
Could you pls suggest something about this? Only Windows restart helps. Then I connect to VPN, disconnect and localhost doesn't work. what can block it and why restart helps?
[image]

**Update**

- start windows, run the app - app works
- start windows, run the app, app works, connect to the VPN - app works
- start windows, run the app, app works, connect to the VPN, app works, disconnect from VPN, add stop work
- start windows, connect to the VPN, start app, app works, disconnect from VPN, add stop work
- start windows, connect to the VPN, disconnect from VPN, start app, add stop work

[image]

Comment: is it still happening even if you close the VPN ( not only disconnecting ) and disable their service ?

can you change your application IP to something other than "127.0.0.1" ? if yes try it if it's working than the Citrix's VPN that cause the problem even when you disconnect from the VPN because it may have their server still runing and interrupting your application

Comment: Make sure the app is still listening after disconnecting from the vpn with something like `netstat -an`. Maybe it's not able to handle re-binding after changing network connection

Comment: Also, I used a webserver app once that would only respond to requests from the host's same subnet (by default), but it would only check at startup. Changing networks via vpn would really trip it up

Comment: @guest777 I cannot change the application IP (it happening for Azure Cosmos Emulator for example)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale you're right, after disconnecting, these are no longer in output, how to fix that? even I restart the app it doesn't help (TCP    127.0.0.1:8081         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:8081         127.0.0.1:49918        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:8081         127.0.0.1:49919        ESTABLISHED)

Comment: @RomanMarusyk does it work in reverse, like if you have the app running first, then connect to the VPN? Look for the app's logs, and see whether it's failing to bind to port 8081 after disconnecting, and why

Comment: the app doesn't have any logs. "does it work in reverse, like if you have the app running first, then connect to the VPN?" - you described the current state, it's not revers. also tried this - start windows, start vpn, disconnect vpn, start app - app does not start. I'll update mu question with cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the old version of Citrix Gateway 12.1.51.19 instead of 22.21.1.103 which solved my problem

Comment: Good job : Better communicate this to Citrix - you have successfully proven that this is bug.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround : Using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` when connecting
might solve the issue.

A solution needs to come from the Citrix client itself.
Try to find some setting in it that relates to the problem,
or get in touch with Citrix Support.

Comment: no, it doesn't solve

Comment: (1) Do you mean that `127.0.0.1` doesn't work either? The local adapter is built-into Windows, as far as I know. Let me know if that's what's happening to you and I'll look into it further. (2) Can it be a firewall problem? (3) Verify also your `%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. (4) Run the command `netsh interface portproxy reset`.

Comment: none of this works. Did you see my question? There are such words -  Also, disable Firewall, etc\hosts is ok, proxy is not set.

Comment: Seems incredible. Could you add to your post the routing table before the VPN when everything worked, and after it when localhost is blocked.

Comment: pls see the updated question

Comment: The VPN driver deleted and didn't return the route for 127.0.0.1! Try this when the problem happens : Run Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator and enter this command : `route add 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 metric 331`.

Comment: Also tried, with no success, it adds  127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.31.216    386, also tried `route add 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 if 1
 OK!` that adds `127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1     76`

Comment: Also see this comment https://superuser.com/questions/1766522/localhost-took-too-long-to-respond-err-connection-timed-out/1767948?noredirect=1#comment2752178_1766522

Comment: I have recreated your problem by using the command `route delete 127.0.0.1`. I then tried every suggestion I could find to recreate this route or restart the loopback interface, but nothing worked. Only restart worked to create the route in a usable way. I think your only remaining option is to ensure that you're using the latest Citrix client version and then signal the bug to Citrix Support.

Comment: I installed the old version 12.1.51.19 instead of 22.21.1.103 which solved my problem Thank you for help